# Remove personality menu from add-in

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins

I am currently working in an Office 365 Excel add-in.
In the desktop version of Office 365 Excel, there is something that the documentation dubs a "personality menu" that is activated by clicking this button in the top right corner on windows:

[image: windows]

The button looks like this on mac:
[image: mac]

I want to remove this option from the add-in, as it obscures part of the screen.

I've tried looking at the add-in manifest and other config files, but have found nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, removing the personality menu is not possible at this time.

I am a Program Manager at Microsoft, and we are currently investigating options for removing/replacing the personality menu to enable both end user and developers to utilize the entire screen space.

Comment: :( Thanks for answering!

Comment: @Abid - As it's been four months, is there an update on the above? Is it now possible to remove/replace the personality menu by any chance? If not, is it possible to at least remove the "Attach Debugger" option?

Comment: I am just wondering if it is a possible to rename the personality menu items? I mean instead of using EN words using the locale words --> For instance, instead of "Get Support" using "Obtenir de l'aide" in FR language and so on.