# Conditionally hide "Attach Debugger" menu item from the personality menu for a Word add-in

Tags: office-js

I maintain a Word add-in with Angular framework version 15. On hovering on the top right corner of the add-in, the personality menu appears as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/attach-debugger-from-task-pane).
The issue is that the menu item "Attach Debugger" always appears in the personality menu.

I looked at existing StackOverflow questions:

- [Remove personality menu from add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58633794/remove-personality-menu-from-add-in)
- [Modifying Personality Menu items in task panes in Office Add-ins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75190882/modifying-personality-menu-items-in-task-panes-in-office-add-ins)
- [Change functionality of Microsoft officejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73810610/change-functionality-of-microsoft-officejs)

which mention that the personality menu is not customizable.

I did not find a clear guidance in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/task-pane-add-ins#personality-menu) that the personality menu is not customizable.

I would like to know if there are any changes to this statement that the personality menu for the Word add-in is not customizable. I am interested to know if the menu item "Attach Debugger" from the personality menu could appear based on a setting since a customer mentioned that the menu item "Attach Debugger" is not needed functionally for the users of the add-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to customize the Personality menu. But it's a good idea. I recommend that you suggest this at [Microsoft Developer Platform Ideas](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform).